# Unable to register service with BizTalk Message Box database

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk

I have a tool in .net framework 3.5 which will create send and receive port on Biztalk server 2006. I am getting an error which says "Unable to register service with BizTalk Message Box database". Need your help.

Please find screenshot below of the error

[image: BtsException]

Comment: Are you using ExplorerOM?

Comment: yes Pieter, i am using 'Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM'

Comment: You need to tell it where to find the BizTalk MessageBox DB.  We have no idea how to do that unless we know what tool you're using.  My guess would be that it's configured to look on the localhost by defautl.

Comment: I got resolved this thing. Actually it was due to access issue, the id with whom i was creating did not have biztalk server access. I tried with different id and it worked. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create send or receive ports normally using ExplorerOM?

Point it to the correct server / instance / port of your SQL Server hosting the BizTalk databases. More specifically, it tries to search for `BizTalkMgmtDb`.

Also note that ExplorerOM is ONLY 32-bit. It cannot run in a 64-bit application. Be sure that your application is 32-bit.